# import pygr into jython failing on C library

Tags: python, c, jython, bioinformatics

I am trying to `import pygr`:

It fails on:

```
>>> import seqfmt
ImportError: No module named seqfmt
```

The program that uses this works fine in Python.  However its calling a C library called `seqfmt` (which has a `C` file and a `PYX` files).  Is this possible to `import` over to `Jython` or since its `C` am I out of luck?

Answer (score 6):

`.PYX` is the file extension used by cython, a tool for writing C extensions for python in a python-like syntax. Cython creates an intermediate file (that's presumably the `.C` file you see, at least it's not in the [git repository](https://github.com/cjlee112/pygr/tree/master/pygr)) and compiles it into a python extension.

Jython does not support CPython extensions yet. From its homepage:

> There are a number of differences. First, Jython programs cannot currently use CPython 
>   extension modules written in C. These modules usually have files with the extension .so, 
>   .pyd or .dll. If you want to use such a module, you should look for an
>   equivalent written in pure Python or Java. However, it is technically
>   feasible to support such extensions, as demonstrated by IronPython.
>   For the next release of Jython, we plan to support the C Python
>   Extension API.

Some cython modules can be easily translated into python, and `seqfmt` is one of them, but pygr has a second cython module, `cnestedlist`, which involves C calls: The lines

```
cdef extern from "apps/maf2nclist.h":
[..]
int readMAFrecord(IntervalMap im[],int n,SeqIDMap seqidmap[],int nseq,
                int lpoStart,int *p_block_len,FILE *ifile,int maxseq,
                long long linecode_count[],int *p_has_continuation)
```

define an external library call. You'd have to translate this library to Python, too.

Just as a side-note regarding the translation: cython can not only be used to wrap C libraries, but also to simply speed up certain parts of a program. In these cases it is pretty straight-forward to translate them into a python module. Have a look into the `seqfmt.pyx` source file, its pretty self-explanatory if you know python.

That all being said, there is a project related to Jython, [JyNI](http://jyni.org/), which aims to support CPython extensions from Jython. It is work-in-progress, so I can't tell if your libraries are supported by it. There are some examples in the github repository, maybe you can get it to work. The readme file claims binary compatibility, so with JyNI enabled you should be able to run your code without any recompiling.